# writing to a text file in a specific path in c#?

Tags: c#

writing to a text file is working good...But my problem is text file is created in different path....

Here is my code...

```
var _logFolderPath = Path.Combine(textboxPath.Text.Trim(), "log");
string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(txtBoxInput.Text, "RM"));

foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
{
string[] x = Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory);
DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textboxPath.Text);
............
}
```

and

```
using (var dest = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(_logFolderPath,subdirectory+ ".txt")))
```

Here i have to store the `subdirectory named text file` in `_logFolderPath` path....But the text files are generared in the subdirectory path...I just need the name of the subdirectory to be created as a text file in `_logFolderPath` path...How to get the name of the subdirectory alone....Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [DirectoryInfo.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Is the using within the foreach?

Comment: DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(subdirectory);
String dirName = dir.Name;

Answer (score 0):

You should use DirectoryInfo instead.  It can give you just the directory name.  Here is a sample

```
DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
foreach (DirectoryInfo s in root.GetDirectories())
{
     Console.Out.WriteLine(s.Name);
}
```